# How to update value of variable for each iteration in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to have the variable "gpa" and "num_of_credits" update based on user input for each time the while loop runs so I can get the average in the end.

**Code:**

```
name = input('Enter your name: ').capitalize()
semester = input(f"{name}, You are calculating your GPA for which semester?: ").lower()
while True:
    course_code = input("Enter your course code: ")
    num_of_credits = float(input(f"Enter the number of credit for {course_code}: "))
    letter_grade = input("Enter the letter grade: ")
    if letter_grade == 'A+':
        letter_grade = 4.3
    elif letter_grade == 'A':
        letter_grade = 4.0
    elif letter_grade == 'A-':
        letter_grade = 3.7
    elif letter_grade == 'B+':
        letter_grade = 3.3
    elif letter_grade == 'B':
        letter_grade = 3.0
    elif letter_grade == 'B-':
        letter_grade = 2.7
    elif letter_grade == 'C+':
        letter_grade = 2.3
    elif letter_grade == 'C':
        letter_grade = 2.0
    elif letter_grade == 'C-':
        letter_grade = 1.7
    elif letter_grade == 'D+':
        letter_grade = 1.3
    elif letter_grade == 'D':
        letter_grade = 1.0
    elif letter_grade == 'D-':
        letter_grade = 0.7
    elif letter_grade == 'F':
        letter_grade = 0.0
    else: 
        print("Please enter a valid letter grade")
    gpa = (num_of_credits) * letter_grade
    
    print(num_of_credits)
    print(gpa)
    cont = input(f"Did you take any other class during {semester}? (y/n): ")
    if cont == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
    print(num_of_credits)
    print(gpa)
letter_grade = float(letter_grade)
cgpa = gpa / num_of_credits
print(f'Your cumulative gpa for {semester} is {cgpa}')
```

This is what I get when I run the code:

**Output**

```
Enter your name: x
X, You are calculating your GPA for which semester?: y
Enter your course code: z1
Enter the number of credit for z1: 3
Enter the letter grade: A
3.0
12.0
Did you take any other class during y? (y/n): y
Enter your course code: z2
Enter the number of credit for z2: 3
Enter the letter grade: B
3.0
9.0
Did you take any other class during y? (y/n): n
Your cumulative gpa for y is 3.0
```

Instead, I want the values to be stored/updated each time the loop runs so I can get the avg in the end.

Any help would be much appreciated!

ps. I am wondering if creating an empty list and then adding new values each time the loop runs would be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track regarding starting with an empty list outside of the loop and adding to it as you go.  To simplify the example, the code below includes the key parts while leaving out everything in between:

```
gpa_list = []
...
while True:
    ...
    gpa = (num_of_credits) * letter_grade
    gpa_list.append(gpa)
    ...
...
avg_gpa = sum(gpa_list) / len(gpa_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I created empty lists for both of the variables and it works perfectly! Appreciate your help!